# How could I get the Node specific ID in Node-Red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I've already created a custom node, and I need to get the ID which displays on the INFO tab along with the type before the flow gets deployed.

So that I could use that ID as a unique id, to do CRUD operations.

[image]

How could I get this? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need it before it's deployed? until it's deployed it shouldn't exist anywhere else but as a graphic on the canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you want is available in the `oneditsave` call back function as follows:

```
...
oneditsave: function(){
  var id = this.id;
  ...
}
```

As I said in the comment, you should only create resources to back a node at the point that the node is deployed as it may never be deployed and there is no way to clean up an undeployed node's resources.

The resources should be created in the javascript file so they can be cleaned up using the `node.on('close',function(done){})`

Comment: i only wanted this info in the label and so included it in the `label:` section

Comment: @northern-bradley but `label` can be a function that can return this dynamically, no need to grab it before the deploy